# Converting unpack code from perl to python

Tags: python, perl, struct

I'm trying to convert the following unpack code to Python:

`my @header = unpack "L2L13SS", $raw;`

I've tried `struct.unpack("<L2L13HH", open(pfc_path,'rb').read(length))` and `struct.unpack("<L2L13BB", open(pfc_path,'rb').read(length))` both give 0 for `header[16]`, the correct value should be 9

The file to unpack is here:
https://github.com/mishari/PMConverter/blob/main/src/tests/data/_PFC._PS

The header has been described in the following way:

```
    # The pfc file seems to start with the following header
    # struct PfcHead
    # {
    #    long id1;            // Seems to contain 0x005344f4
    #    long id2;            // Seems to contain 0x01234567
    #    long rsvd[13];       // Zeros
    #    short s1;            // Seems like number of fields minus one?
    #    short s2;            // Number of field structures
    # };
```

Comment: Try `struct.unpack('15I2H',header)`

Comment: `struct.calcsize('L')` will probably output `8`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Understanding the Perl code**

`L2L13SS` can also be written as

- `L L L13 S S`
- `L15 S2`
- `L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L S S`

As per the [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack) and [my chart](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11111036),

- `L`: 32-bit unsigned integer in native byte order.
- `S`: 16-bit unsigned integer in native byte order.

---

**Equivalent Python code**

`struct.unpack` offers similar functionality.

- `L` with `=`: 32-bit unsigned integer in native byte order.
- `H` with `=`: 16-bit unsigned integer in native byte order.

With `struct.unpack`, `=` is associated with the entire format string rather than individual specifiers. Also, repetition accounts are expected before the letter.

So,

```perl
my @header = unpack "L15 S2", $raw;
```

is equivalent to

```py
header = struct.unpack('= 15L 2H', raw)
```

---

**Parsing a binary dump of the C structure**

But you're not trying to replicate the Perl code; you're trying to read in that C structure.

The Perl pattern being used (`L15 S2`) isn't equivalent to the C structure you posted.

- `long` is a signed type.
- `long` may be longer than 32-bits.
- `short` is a signed typed.
- `short` may be longer than 16-bits.
- The C compiler is free to put padding between the fields, though no compiler would for this structure.
- The C compiler is free to put padding at the end. This is possible say on a compiler with 16-bit shorts and 64-bit longs. This is actually very common.

`l!15 s!2` would be closer to the correct pattern.

- `l!`: Native `long` in native byte order.
- `s!`: Native `short` in native byte order.

But that assumes there's no padding, and that's a problem. That's why [Convert::Binary::C](https://metacpan.org/pod/Convert::Binary::C) would be a better choice than `unpack` for handling native types in Perl. (Make sure to use `Alignment => 0`.)

In Python, you could use the following to more accurately represent the C structure:

```py
header = struct.unpack('@ 15l 2h', raw)
```

or just

```py
header = struct.unpack('15l 2h', raw)
```

With `@` (or no symbol at all), `struct.pack` will add inter-field padding where appropriate.

```
$ cat a.c
#include <stdio.h>

struct Foo {
   char  c;
   short s;
};

int main(void) {
   printf("%zu\n", sizeof(struct Foo));
}

$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic a.c -o a && ./a
4

$ python3 -c 'import struct; print(len(struct.pack("bh", 0, 0)))'
4
```

However, it doesn't add trailing padding when it should.

```
$ cat a.c
#include <stdio.h>

struct PfcHead {
   long id1;
   long id2;
   long rsvd[13];
   short s1;
   short s2;
};

int main(void) {
   printf("%zu\n", sizeof(struct PfcHead));
}

$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic a.c -o a && ./a
128

$ python3 -c 'import struct; print(len(struct.pack("15l 2h", *((0,)*17))))'
124
```

I don't know of an easy way to handle structs with trailing padding in Python.